# Why are these two IMAP Search results different from one another?

Tags: email, imap, imaplib

I'm using imaplib, and trying to fetch emails with a certain subject header value.

My code:

```
    res, tmp = self.mail.uid('search', None, 'HEADER Subject "SUBJECT_HERE"')
    print(tmp)
    print(res)

    print("test 2 goes:")
    rr, tt = self.mail.search(None, 'HEADER Subject "SUBJECT_HERE"')
    print(tt)
    print(rr)
```

Result:

> [b'225 232 323 324 346 366 382 419 420 425 450 463 517 607 670 751 833
>   911 1043 1129 1133 1134 1287 1350 1799 1854 1957 1960 1962 1991 2005
>   2040 2071 2110 2119 2121 2153 2158 2182 2188 2189 2228 2230 2239 2249
>   2334 2335 2372 2378 2396 2435 2497 2567 2568 2573 2574 2575 2632 2633
>   2634 2648 2649 2709 2785 2819 2821 2828 2829 2868 2885 2895 2902 2906
>   2920 2993 2997 2998 3000 3001 3009']     OK      test 2 goes:
>   [b'220 227 318 319 340 360 376 413 414 419 444 457 511 601 664 745 827
>   905 1037 1123 1127 1128 1281 1344 1793 1848 1951 1954 1956 1985 1999
>   2034 2065 2104 2113 2115 2147 2152 2176 2182 2183 2222 2224 2233 2243
>   2328 2329 2366 2372 2390 2429 2491 2561 2562 2567 2568 2569 2625 2626
>   2627 2641 2642 2702 2778 2812 2814 2821 2822 2861 2878 2888 2895 2899
>   2913 2986 2990 2991 2993 2994 3002']     OK

I thought that those two commands result in the same results.

But as shown above, those two fetch different emails.

What is the difference??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One (`SEARCH`) returns message sequence numbers (MSN), which are numbered from 1 to N and change as messages are added and deleted.  A message that is number 5 now could be number 4 tomorrow if you delete a message before it.

The other (`UID SEARCH`) returns UIDs, which do not change as messages are deleted.  They're two completely different set of identifiers.  A message with UID 5 will remain UID 5 until it is deleted it (or moved, etc.).

The UID will never reused in that incarnation of a folder.  If the folder is deleted and recreated, or the mail server is rebuilt, the folder's `UIDVALIDITY` should change so you can detect that your cache is no longer valid.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! Okay, I got the difference between MSN and UID. Then, when a mail with UID 1 is deleted, does a new mail get that UID(1), or that UID(1) is never occupied by any other email?

Comment: Unless the mail server is rebuilt or the folder is recreated with a new `UIDVALIDITY`, UID 1 will never be used again in that folder.  That is what the `UIDVALIDITY` is for, it is a serial number of sorts to let you know if your UID cache is valid.  If you delete and recreate a folder with the same name, it will have a new UIDVALIDITY so you can detect that.  I've updated the answer with some information on that.